# Android - Playing file when clicking a button inside a listview

Tags: android, listview, audio, onclick, media-player

I have a chat functionality where I am including voice messages. The code for recording, sending file to server and insertion on the list is fine too.

I my layout file (list_item_chat), I have a play button, a seekbar and two textviews which shows the current time and duration for the playing file (streaming):

list_item_chat.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/layout_main_container"
        android:gravity="right">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:id="@+id/chat_left_post"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc_list_item_icon"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:src="@drawable/chat_left_post"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_content_all_items"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/listview_item_chat_left_shape"
            android:minWidth="120dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minWidth="120dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/list_item_chat_post_date"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/bee_text_default_color"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:layout_gravity="left" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/list_item_chat_post_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:autoLink="all"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/list_item_chat_post_date"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layout_player_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/list_item_chat_post_date"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/btnPlayAudioStreaming"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/listen_voice_message"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_play"
                        android:tag="1" />

                    <SeekBar
                        android:id="@+id/skbAudioCurrentState"
                        android:layout_width="250dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnPlayAudioStreaming"
                        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btnPlayAudioStreaming"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/lblCurrentDuration"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/bee_text_default_color"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/skbAudioCurrentState"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btnPlayAudioStreaming"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
                        android:visibility="visible" />


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/lblTotalDuration"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/bee_text_default_color"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/skbAudioCurrentState"
                        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/skbAudioCurrentState"
                        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/skbAudioCurrentState"
                        android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
                        android:visibility="visible" />

                </RelativeLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc_list_item_icon"
            android:src="@drawable/chat_right_post"
            android:id="@+id/chat_right_post"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I have created a listener inside my activity (ChatActivity) and set the listener for each of my PlayButton inside my adapter (ChatPostAdapter):

ChatActivity.java:

```
public ChatPostAdapter adapterLoadingMore; //adapter global variable

//Binding adapter
adapterLoadingMore = (ChatPostAdapter) ((HeaderViewListAdapter) mList.getAdapter()).getWrappedAdapter();
adapterLoadingMore.setPlayPauseButtonListener(ChatActivity.this);

//method for playing audio file
public void playVoiceMessage(final View v, ChatPostItem chatPostItem) {
        if (mp == null) {
            mp = new MediaPlayer();
        } else {
            mp.reset();
        }

    String url = chatPostItem.getAudioFile();
    try {
        mp.setDataSource(url);
        mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mp.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                return false;
            }
        });
        mp.prepareAsync();
        mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.start();
            }
        });
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                mp = null;

                adapterLoadinMore.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onPlayPauseIsClickListener(View v, int position, ChatPostItem chatPostItem, int play) {
    if (play == 1) {
        playVoiceMessage(v, chatPostItem);
    } else if (play == 2) {
        if (mp != null) {
            if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                mp.pause();
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (mp != null) {
            mp.start();
        }
    }
}
```

ChatPostAdapter.java:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        try {
            if (position >= 0 && position < navDrawerItems.size()) {
                final ChatPostItem item = navDrawerItems.get(position);
                if (item != null) {
                    UserData user = ((MyApplication) this.context.getApplicationContext()).getUser();
                    final ViewHolder holder;
                    if (v == null) {
                        holder = new ViewHolder();

                        v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_chat, parent, false);

                        holder.Post = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_chat_post_text);
                        holder.CreationDatetime = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_chat_post_date);
                        holder.CurrentTime = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lblCurrentDuration);
                        holder.SeekBarCurrentDuration = (SeekBar) v.findViewById(R.id.skbAudioCurrentState);
                        holder.PlayButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.btnPlayAudioStreaming);
                        holder.CreationDatetime = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_chat_post_date);
                        holder.layout_content_all_items = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.layout_content_all_items);
                        holder.layout_main_container = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.layout_main_container);
                        holder.chat_right_post = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.chat_right_post);
                        holder.chat_left_post = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.chat_left_post);
                        holder.layout_player_content = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.layout_player_content);
                        holder.lblTotalDuration = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lblTotalDuration);

                        v.setTag(holder);
                    } else {
                        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();

                        if (position != mButtonPosition) {
                            holder.PlayButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_play);
                            holder.SeekBarCurrentDuration.setProgress(0);
                            holder.SeekBarCurrentDuration.setMax(100);
                        } else {
                            holder.PlayButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_pause);
                            //get current progress and current playing time
                            //set it on the tag for the respective View and bla bla bla bla...

                        }
                    }

                    showHideLayoutButtons(holder, item, user);


                    holder.PlayButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            if (playPauseButtonListener != null) {

                                int PlayStopButtonState = Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString());
                                int previousPosition = mButtonPosition;

                                if (PlayStopButtonState == 1) {
                                    //necessary to control recycling
                                    mButtonPosition = position;

                                    v.setTag(2);
                                    playPauseButtonListener.onPlayPauseIsClickListener(v, position, item, PlayStopButtonState);

                                    ((ImageButton) v).setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_pause);
                                } else if (PlayStopButtonState == 2) {
                                    mButtonPosition = -1;

                                    v.setTag(3);
                                    playPauseButtonListener.onPlayPauseIsClickListener(v, position, item, PlayStopButtonState);

                                    ((ImageButton) v).setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_play);
                                } else {
                                    mButtonPosition = -1;

                                    v.setTag(2);
                                    playPauseButtonListener.onPlayPauseIsClickListener(v, position, item, PlayStopButtonState);

                                    ((ImageButton) v).setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_pause);
                                }

                                if (previousPosition != -1)
                                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    try {
                        SimpleDateFormat originalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(US_DATE_TIME, Locale.US);
                        SimpleDateFormat targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(STANDARD_DATE_TIME, Locale.US);
                        Date date = originalFormat.parse(item.getCreatedDateTime());

                        holder.CreationDatetime.setText(targetFormat.format(date));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        holder.CreationDatetime.setText(item.getCreatedDateTime());
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.w("Adaptor getView", e.toString());
        }
        return v;
    }

OnPlayPauseButtonClickListener playPauseButtonListener;

    public interface OnPlayPauseButtonClickListener {
        void onPlayPauseIsClickListener(View button, int position, ChatPostItem chatPostItem, int play);
    }

    public void setPlayPauseButtonListener(OnPlayPauseButtonClickListener playPauseButtonListener) {
        this.playPauseButtonListener = playPauseButtonListener;
    }
}
```

When I click play, the file starts to play correctly. I made the play/pause control works fine too.

The problem is:

I'm having trouble when playing some OTHER file inside that list! I have no idea how to control this properly.
I've tried any ways that I know, researched multiple times and now I'm here asking for help. I would appreciate if someone who made something close to this could help!

Thank you very much!